# Syntax highlighting for "C like" files

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a number of files with a syntax almost
identical to C, though the files have suffixes
such as `.t`, `.sc`

I would like to have the same syntax highlighting
that I have for standard C files ending with the
suffix `.c`.

For any one file I know I can execute:

```
:set filetype=c
```

but it is cumbersome to have to execute that
command every time.

Is there something I can add to my .vimrc file
so that some files with specific suffixes
can have "C" syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can add the following:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.t, *.sc setfiletype c
augroup END
```

However, to help keep your .vimrc tidy, you could also put that in a separate file called filetypes.vim in your .vim directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this in your ~/.vimrc, or in a file in ~/.vim/ftdetect:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.t,*.sc set filetype=c
```

Also see:

```
:help new-filetype
```